# Looking for ideas for a site map page on the website

Tags: website-design, sitemap

We have a site with a lot of pages. We are in some of the final stages of redesigning the site and am looking for some examples of good site map designs we can be inspired by.

Have you seen any good designs we can look at to be inspired by?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Footer sitemaps](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/trends/modern-sitemap-and-footer/) are very common nowadays.

Comment: I found that site in my Google searches as was using that. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [sitemap XML format](http://www.sitemaps.org/) to address compliance and to help out most of the major searchbots spider your site.

Since this is just an XML file that contains links to different pages, there really isn't much to consider in terms of *design* rather **content**.